# Grass 3D View does not show data

Tags: grass-gis, 3d

I created a raster file using interpolation (bspline and idw). The original vector data were GPS elevation data I collected on the ground (in Greece). After interpolation, the file contains information such as this:

```
north: 38.2179846
south: 38.2173841
east: 22.1286094
west: 22.1281249
rows: 499
cols: 403
21.031 21.032 21.033 21.034 21.035 21.036 21.037 21.038 21.039 21.039 21.04 21.041 21.042 21.043 21.043 21.044 21.045 21.045 21.046 21.046 21.047 21.047 21.048 21.048 21.049 21.049 21.05 21.05 21.05 21.051 21.051 21.051 21.051 21.051 21.051 21.052 21.052 21.052 21.052 21.052 21.052 21.051 21.051 21.051 21.051
```

... etc.

Everything in the file looks ok and it displays well in 2D:

[image: raster image showing computation region]

The problem is when I change the view from 2D to 3D view nothing shows at all. I've tried zooming in/out, full extent, but nothing happens.

Could it be a problem of scale and, if so, how do I go about solving it?

This is the output of computational region:
[image: g.region -p and g.region -pl]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to the 3D problem, you clearly have, I believe, an error with the coordinate system. Your raster (and the LOCATION) are declared as UTM zone 34, but the coordinate values are numbers of the order 22-30. In UTM you would have values usually above 100000 for X and in the millions for Y. Since your original points are GPS collected, then I guess you should have a longitude/latitude CRS, based on EPSG 4326, *not* UTM.

I suggest you first create a new LOCATION, with CRS based on 4326, import the points in that LOCATION, redo your interpolation, then try the 3D viewer.